# Detect font while typing in applications like Text edit

Tags: cocoa, macos

I want my application to detect whatever has been typed applications like text edit or text area of any other applications.

I am using Mac.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Any keystrokes, like a key logger, or any test that is visible on the screen, like OCR, or any keystrokes that become visible text?

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't mean what typefaces are visible.

Comment: keystrokes could be tapped. Thats not the case. I need to detect the font currently active where typing is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accessible from the text view's -textStorage, which is a subclass of NSMutableAttributedString/NSAttributedString. You can get the attributes (including font) for a given range. Expanding on that, you can ask the text view for it's typing attributes, which are the same thing NSAttributedString uses.

That said, the only way to get this reliably from other applications is to use input managers or an unsavory code injection a la ApplicationEnhancer.